# Chrome JS memory crash

Tags: jquery, animation, memory, crash

im using pulse effect on some buttons and blinding effect on div borders. About 13 div layers with blinding borders.

I noticed that chrome gives oh snap error after some time. About 5-6mins when i leave page open.

This is my JS code:

http://pastebin.com/C9BkqmGn

Im really not good at this kind of animation so maybe anyone could give any advice how to reduce memory problems and avoid oh snap crashes? Using chrome.

Comment: you need to post the complete code (html + js) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Html code: just simple button and a few div layers with assigned class to use "pulse" effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok without the repro my first guess would be that you are reaching Chrome V8 memory limit which is around 1GB (check how much memory the chrome tab process is using when the crash happens). Also see here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/c1-h945Bmns and here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=847 . I will check it out if im able to reproduce the issue.